# Issues with migrating SharePoint 2010 from one AD to another

Tags: active-directory

I currently have an AD which needs some work, and are building a new one and assigning a trust.

However I'm also doing a SP 2010 build. Will there be any issues if I hook SP 2010 up to the current (old) AD, and then move to the new AD after Prod?

Will there be duplicates of user objects, or any admin mess at all? Is it worth just holding out and building onto the new AD?

or will it possibly navigate the trust and follow user objects as they pass from one AD to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At work, we frequently migrate content databases from one AD (our prod environment) to a completely different one with a different domain (our dev environments). I've observed that the users from the previous AD still remain in the site collection (with their entries in permission lists intact), and you can still view their details as imported from the previous AD. But you probably can't do much with those 'dead' users. I suspect that if I pushed the content db back to prod again, those users would be 'resuscitated'.

I haven't ever done what you're thinking of doing, so I can only really speculate as to what might happen. The ideal outcome is that SharePoint will automatically wire up the existing SP users to profiles in your new AD, based on display name. However, I suspect SP identifies users by their SIDs or something equally specific which will change between ADs. In this case, it probably won't just work straight away, and you might have to use STSADM migrateuser.

Comment: It looks like it is going to work fine. As we migrate the users across we just need to make sure we re-add them to their new groups. As we remove the old AD, SP should clean them out, just as if we had deleted them.